# Decoding a histogram

Tags: java, performance

I'm writing this as a follow-up for my previous question posted [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/191870/transcoding-of-a-large-histogram):

I've successfully decoded a large histogram into a byte array, which is written to a file. I'm now focusing on returning the byte array back to the token-based String. Details on how the tokens work are in the previous example.

I've created a method, below, which takes the byte array as read from the file, and outputs a char array. Due to the unknown size of the output as this point, i'm using a StringBuilder to append the result of the byte array. The `DecodingResult` class is just a simple POJO with the output `String` as a `char[]` and the size of the histogram as an `int`.

```
 /** Decodes the raw byte into a decoding result object.
 * @param bytes bytes to decode
 * @return decodingResult object
 */
public static DecodingResult decodeBinarySPECtoRAW(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    int height = 0;
    int length = 0;
    int val;
    int histogramLength = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        char token = (char) bytes[i];

        sb.append(token);
        boolean nonSpecial = false;
        for (Token t : Token.values()) {
            if (token == t.name().charAt(0)) {
                nonSpecial = true;
                height = t.getHeight();
                length = t.getLength();
            }
        }

        if (nonSpecial) {
            //length
            if (length != 0 && length != 1) {
                if (length == 8) {
                    //1 byte
                    sb.append(getPaddedString(String.valueOf(bytes[i + 1] & 0xFF), 3));
                    histogramLength += bytes[i + 1] & 0xFF;
                    i++;
                } else if (length == 16) {
                    //2 bytes
                    val = Tools.convertFromByteArray2(bytes[i + 1], bytes[i + 2]);
                    histogramLength += val;
                    sb.append(getPaddedString(String.valueOf(val), 5));
                    i += 2;
                } else {
                    //4 bytes
                    val = Tools.convertFromByteArray4(bytes[i + 1], bytes[i + 2], bytes[i + 3], bytes[i + 4]);
                    histogramLength += val;
                    sb.append(getPaddedString(String.valueOf(val), 10));

                    i += 4;
                }
            } else {
                histogramLength++;
            }

            //height
            if (height != 0 && height != 1) {
                if (height == 8) {
                    //1 byte
                    sb.append(getPaddedString(String.valueOf(bytes[i + 1] & 0xFF), 3));
                    i++;
                } else if (height == 16) {
                    //2 bytes
                    val = Tools.convertFromByteArray2(bytes[i + 1], bytes[i + 2]);
                    sb.append(getPaddedString(String.valueOf(val), 5));
                    i += 2;
                } else {
                    //4 bytes
                    val = Tools.convertFromByteArray4(bytes[i + 1], bytes[i + 2], bytes[i + 3], bytes[i + 4]);
                    sb.append(getPaddedString(String.valueOf(val), 10));
                    i += 4;
                }
            }
        } else {
            switch (token) {
                case 'R': {
                    int numReads = (int) bytes[i + 1] & 0xFF;
                    i++;
                    sb.append(getPaddedString(String.valueOf(numReads), 3));
                    for (int j = 0; j < numReads; j++) {
                        int nextNum = bytes[i + 1] & 0xFF;
                        sb.append(getPaddedString(String.valueOf(nextNum), 3));
                        histogramLength++;
                        i++;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 'S': {
                    int numReads = (int) bytes[i + 1] & 0xFF;
                    i++;
                    sb.append(getPaddedString(String.valueOf(numReads), 3));
                    for (int j = 0; j < numReads; j++) {
                        histogramLength++;

                        sb.append(getPaddedString(String.valueOf(Tools.convertFromByteArray2(bytes[i + 1], bytes[i + 2])), 5));
                        i += 2;

                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 'T': {
                    sb.append(getPaddedString(String.valueOf(Tools.convertFromByteArray4(bytes[i + 1], bytes[i + 2], bytes[i + 3], bytes[i + 4])), 10));
                    i += 4;
                    sb.append(getPaddedString(String.valueOf(Tools.convertFromByteArray4(bytes[i + 1], bytes[i + 2], bytes[i + 3], bytes[i + 4])), 10));
                    i += 4;
                    break;
                }
                case 'U': {
                    sb.append(getPaddedString(String.valueOf(Tools.convertFromByteArray4(bytes[i + 1], bytes[i + 2], bytes[i + 3], bytes[i + 4])), 10));
                    i += 4;
                    break;
                }
                case 'V': {
                    List<Byte> VBytes = new ArrayList<>();
                    boolean escapeFound = false;
                    while (!escapeFound) {
                        if (i + 1 < bytes.length) {
                            if (bytes[i + 1] == 0) escapeFound = true;
                            else {
                                VBytes.add(bytes[i + 1]);
                                i += 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    for (byte b : VBytes) {
                        sb.append((char) b);
                    }
                    sb.append(getPaddedString(String.valueOf(bytes[i + 1] & 0xFF), 3));
                    i += 1;
                    break;
                }
                case 'W': {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                        sb.append("000");
                        i += 1;
                    }
                    sb.append(getPaddedString(String.valueOf(Tools.convertFromByteArray4(bytes[i + 1], bytes[i + 2], bytes[i + 3], bytes[i + 4])), 10));
                    i += 4;
                    break;
                }
                case 'X': {
                    sb.append(getPaddedString(String.valueOf(bytes[i + 1] & 0xFF), 3));
                    i += 1;
                    //get length of the statement
                    int statementLength = bytes[i + 1] & 0xFF;
                    sb.append(getPaddedString(String.valueOf(statementLength), 3));
                    i += 1;
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < i + 1 + statementLength; j++) {
                        sb.append((char) bytes[j]);
                    }
                    i += statementLength;
                    sb.append(getPaddedString(String.valueOf(Tools.convertFromByteArray2(bytes[i + 1], bytes[i + 2])), 5));
                    i += 2;
                    //endseq
                    int endLength = bytes[i + 1];
                    sb.append(getPaddedString(String.valueOf(endLength), 3));
                    i += 1;
                    if (endLength != 0) {
                        for (int j = i + 1; j < i + 1 + endLength; j++) {
                            sb.append((char) bytes[j]);
                        }
                        i += endLength;
                    }

                    //flankseq
                    int flankLength = bytes[i + 1];
                    sb.append(getPaddedString(String.valueOf(flankLength), 3));
                    i += 1;
                    if (flankLength != 0) {
                        for (int j = i + 1; j < i + 1 + flankLength; j++) {
                            sb.append((char) bytes[j]);
                        }
                        i += flankLength;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 'Y': {
                    //must be Y
                    sb.append(getPaddedString(String.valueOf(Tools.convertFromByteArray4(bytes[i + 1], bytes[i + 2], bytes[i + 3], bytes[i + 4])), 10));
                    i += 4;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    return new DecodingResult(sb.toString().toCharArray(), histogramLength);

}

public static String getPaddedString(String s, int max){
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(max);
    for(int i = 0; i < max - s.length(); i++){
        b.append('0');
    }
    b.append(s);
    return b.toString();
}
```

The token code, just so no one has to go back and forth to the last post:

```
/** All lengths and heights in bits.
 * All 1's are to be ignored in writing
 * i.e 1 - 0 is transcoded as A.
 * 1 -1 is transcoded as E
 * 1 - 209 is transcoded as I209
 * 1 - 2 is transcoded as I002
 * 1 - 40000 is transcoded as M40000
 * 1 - 290 is transcoded as M00290
 */
 public enum Token {

A (1, 0),
B (8, 0),
I (1 ,8),
E (1, 1),
F (8, 1),
J (8, 8),
N (8,16),
M (1,16),
C (16,0),
D (32,0),
G (16,1),
H (32,1),
K (16,8),
L (32,8),
O (16,16),
P (32,16),
Q (16,32),
Z (1,32);


private final int length;
private final int height;


Token(int length, int height) {
    this.length = length;
    this.height = height;
}

public int getLength() {
    return length;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}
```

}

Also the `convertFromByteArray` code.

```
public static int convertFromByteArray2(byte byte1, byte byte2){
    return ((byte2 & 0xFF) << 8 | (byte1 & 0xFF));
}

public static int convertFromByteArray4(byte byte1, byte byte2, byte byte3, byte byte4){
    return byte1 << 24 | (byte2 & 0xFF) << 16 | (byte3 & 0xFF) << 8 | (byte4 & 0xFF);
}
```

There are two processes here that are repeated, and are taking a lot of time but i'm not sure if there's a better way of doing it. The first is the `byte` -> `string` process. I have created a padding method to remove the use of `String.format`

Secondly, It's having to loop through every `Token` in the list to find the corresponding correct one.

Comment: I thought you were told about the cost of `String.format()`

Comment: @SharonBenAsher This new code avoids `String.format()`.

Answer (score 2):

The loop can simply be replaced with a lookup map which you prepare once before the process runs:

```
Map<Character, Token> tokenLookup = EnumSet.allOf(Token.class).stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(tok -> tok.name().charAt(0), Function.identity()));
```

Then, instead of the loop just:

```
Token t = tokenLookup.get(token);
if(t != null) {
    nonSpecial = true;
    height = t.getHeight();
    length = t.getLength();
}
```

Regarding the `getPaddedString()` method: you could at least eliminate the repeated call to s.length() for every loop operation:

```
for(int i = max - s.length(); i > 0; i--)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Thats definitely a better way that to do it than iterating through the Tokens.